# In Scala how to compare current values with previous values while processing a stream?

Tags: scala

I am new to scala so not sure how to approach this problem ? Basically I am trying to find moving average crossovers for a stream of quotes.
I am not sure how to get to the previous values to compare them with the current values ?

```
if ( fastMovingAverage(n-1) > slowMovingAverage(n-1) && fastMovingAverage(n) < slowMovingAverage(n) )
then do some action



package com.example.csv

import scala.io.Source


object FileParser {
  val TIMESTAMP_LOCATION = 3
  val BID_LOCATION = 4
  val OFFER_LOCATION = 5
  val FAST_WINDOW_SIZE = 5
  val SLOW_WINDOW_SIZE = 10

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val records = Source.fromFile("Sample.csv")
    .getLines()
    .drop(1)
    .map(_.split(","))
    .takeWhile( _ != null)
    .sliding(SLOW_WINDOW_SIZE , 1)
    .foreach(x => movingAverage(x))
  }

  def movingAverage(numbers: Seq[Array[String]]) = {
    val listOfBids = numbers.map(x => x(BID_LOCATION).toDouble)
    val slowAverage = listOfBids.reduceLeft(_ + _)/numbers.length
    val fastListOfBids = listOfBids.takeRight(FAST_WINDOW_SIZE)
    val fastAverage = fastListOfBids.reduceLeft(_ + _)/fastListOfBids.length
    println("Slow Average " + slowAverage + " Fast Average " + fastAverage)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is to use the `zip` operation on `slowAverage` and `fastAverage` to combine the lists and then find the difference of the zipped elements. When the difference changes from a negative value to a positive value this indicates that the fast average has crossed above(greater) the  slow average.

Here's the data I used and a longer example:

```
Price      Fast Average(2)  Slow Average(4) Diff
9           
8           8.5     
7           7.5     
6           6.5             7.5              -1
5           5.5             6.5              -1
5           5               5.75             -0.75
6           5.5             5.5               0
7           6.5             5.75              0.75
8           7.5             6.5               1
9           8.5             7.5               1
```

[image: Moving Average Crossover Example]

Google Docs Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Alfb-wgy-zTddHdwU2stS0U5ZUxtN2cwdWFoeWNPZFE&usp=sharing

Most recent price is last.

Let's see it in Scala:

```
scala> val prices = List(9,8,7,6,5,5,6,7,8,9)
prices: List[Int] = List(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> val fastAverage = prices.sliding(2).toList.map(xs => xs.sum / 2.0)
fastAverage: List[Double] = List(8.5, 7.5, 6.5, 5.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5)

scala> val slowAverage = prices.sliding(4).toList.map(xs => xs.sum / 4.0)
slowAverage: List[Double] = List(7.5, 6.5, 5.75, 5.5, 5.75, 6.5, 7.5)
```

Zip together `fastAverage` and `slowAverage` but since they are different sizes we take the last seven of `fastAverage` with `takeRight`.

```
scala> val zipped = fastAverage.takeRight(7) zip slowAverage
zipped: List[(Double, Double)] = List((6.5,7.5), (5.5,6.5), (5.0,5.75), (5.5,5.5), (6.5,5.75), (7.5,6.5), (8.5,7.5))
```

Take the difference of the zipped averages. A change from negative to positive(>=0) indicates that the fast average is greater than the slow average aka bullish moving average crossover.

```
scala> zipped.map(x => x._1 - x._2)
res44: List[Double] = List(-1.0, -1.0, -0.75, 0.0, 0.75, 1.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: Don't use `takeRight` for streams, as it may result in infinite or very long evaluation. `drop` of sliding window size seems more appropriate. Maybe replacing `List` with `Stream` in the example would be better to answer the question.